# Speed up request to same mysql server, different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pretty simple mysql request, 
 1. request calls to table to get an id, if an id exists function ends, if no id, then the id is not banned and 2nd requests, see if the id exists in public table, if no it adds, if it does it counts up 1 for a page view.

Currently this function seems to be causing a serious slow down.
af_ban table has about 8000 rows
af_freefeed table has about 1,000,000 rows.  About 10,000 rows added per day.

```
function pageview($pageid, $pagename){
$sql=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anotherfeedv3.af_ban WHERE pageid = '".$pageid."'"));
    if(!$sql){
        $sql=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT pageid FROM anotherfeedv3.af_freefeed WHERE pageid = '".$pageid."'"));
            if(!$sql){
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `anotherfeedv3`.`af_freefeed` (`id`, `pageid`, `userid`, `views`, `pagename`) VALUES (NULL, \''.$pageid.'\', \'\', \'1\', \''.htmlspecialchars($pagename, ENT_QUOTES).'\');';
            $insert=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error! in Insert '.$pageid.' SQL');
            }else{
            $sql = 'UPDATE `anotherfeedv3`.`af_freefeed` SET `pagename` = \''.htmlspecialchars($pagename, ENT_QUOTES).'\', views=views+1 WHERE `af_freefeed`.`pageid` = '.$pageid.';';
            //$sql = 'UPDATE `anotherfeedv3`.`af_freefeed` SET views=views+1 WHERE `af_freefeed`.`pageid` = '.$pageid.';';
            $update=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Failed update of '.$pageid.' in mysql.');
        }
    }
};
```

Is there a better way i can write this?

---

Solution!

```
function pageview($pageid, $pagename){
$q = sprintf('SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM anotherfeedv3.af_ban WHERE pageid = %d', $pageid);
$r = mysql_query($q);
$a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
if($a['numrows'] > 0){ /* ... */ }else {
    $q = sprintf('SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM anotherfeedv3.af_freefeed WHERE pageid = %d', $pageid);
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    $a = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
    if($a['numrows'] > 0){ /* ... */ 
    $sql = 'UPDATE `anotherfeedv3`.`af_freefeed` SET `pagename` = \''.htmlspecialchars($pagename, ENT_QUOTES).'\', views=views+1 WHERE `af_freefeed`.`pageid` = '.$pageid.';';
            //$sql = 'UPDATE `anotherfeedv3`.`af_freefeed` SET views=views+1 WHERE `af_freefeed`.`pageid` = '.$pageid.';';
    $update=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Failed update of '.$pageid.' in mysql.');
    }else {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `anotherfeedv3`.`af_freefeed` (`id`, `pageid`, `userid`, `views`, `pagename`) VALUES (NULL, \''.$pageid.'\', \'\', \'1\', \''.htmlspecialchars($pagename, ENT_QUOTES).'\');';
            $insert=mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error! in Insert '.$pageid.' SQL');
    }
}
```

Comment: `mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT * ...'))` seems like it could be replaced with some variation of `'SELECT COUNT...'`  In fact, the first two queries look like this.  Since you don't really care about the result set, only the number of results (actually, only whether results exist) skip generating the result set.

Comment: could you show me an example?  or should i just replace * with COUNT

Comment: No don't do that -- that won't work -- give me a minute and I'll throw an example in an answer.

Comment: This does not answer your question but just so you know, you may want to consider using [`PDO Statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) since the deprecated `mysql_query` method is pretty vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: thank you mattedgod, i am still pretty new to mysql so any information is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these rows:

```
$sql=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM anotherfeedv3.af_ban WHERE pageid = '".$pageid."'"));
if(!$sql){ /* ... */ }
```

It appears that you're only interested in whether results exist.

If thats the case, you could replace it with something like:

```
$q = sprintf('SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows FROM anotherfeedv3.af_ban WHERE pageid = %d', $pageid);
$r = mysql_query($q);
$a = mysql_fetch_assoc();
if($a['numrows'] > 0){ /* ... */ }
```

You could condense this, but I split it up pretty liberally for ease of understanding.

Basically, this lets MySQL determine the number of rows without generating a results set.

Further, you could use this technique to combine the first two queries:

```
$q = 'SELECT (';
$q.= '    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anotherfeedv3.af_ban WHERE pageid = %d';
$q.= ') AS banrows, (';
$q.= '    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM anotherfeedv3.af_freefeed WHERE pageid = %d';
$q.= ') AS freerows';
$r = mysql_query(sprintf($q, $pageid, $pageid);
$a = mysql_fetch_assoc();
```

The result of the query will be one row with two columns (banrows, freerows).  The values will be the number of rows that match the respective queries above.

You would then use `$a['banrows']` and `$a['freerows']` to get the row counts for your later logic.

If you're running this query multiple times, there may be some additional performance improvement to be seen if you use PDO and [`PDO::prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).

Comment: let me give this a whirl, ill post back with results and mark if works, thanks so much for helping me with this by the way.

Comment: You can optimize more by changing `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(1)` and `mysql_num_rows()` instead using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and `$a['numrows']`.

Comment: i was reading about pdo here on overflow but seems php.net is down or i am having issues connecting.

Comment: `COUNT(1)` would optimize it further, especially if the table contained multiple columns, but `mysql_num_rows()` wouldn't work in the single-query case I described and would likely *decrease* performance as you're requiring mysql to generate a results set just to count the rows.

Comment: @jedwards You're right about `mysql_num_rows()`, sorry about that. I think if you instead using `COUNT()` function, use `SELECT 1`, maybe can optimize more (I didn't benchmarked yet).

Comment: ok after an hour of tests, this fast request but does not work, it will only do the insert.  not the update, and does not see the banned ids.

Comment: i did above in my quest under solution, to update though, it was my mistake i left the %d in sprintf, i just changed it to a string and all is well...  thank you all so much.